# Adding a header during saving of file in Vim

Tags: vim, save

I have started using Vim for my C(++) programming. But I have 1 problem. Is there any way, how to add the header template to the every file I save (if it weren't added)? The adding of the header works only with creating the a new file for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have something like this in your .vimrc:

```
au BufWritePost *.cpp call InsertHeader()


fun! InsertHeader()
    if search('patterninyourheader', 'bwn') == 0
        0r header.txt
        w
    endif
endfun
```

This will insert the header on every save if one is not there yet, so that's not very efficient. It's better to write a script to search for files that have no header and insert one rather than checking it every time you save changes to the file.